# Java Proxy Servlet shows raw html on browser

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am using below code

```
public class ProxyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";   
    public ProxyServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                                //  Create Get request dynamically to remote server
        String url = "http://internalserver/path";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response1 = new StringBuffer();

        ServletOutputStream sout = response.getOutputStream();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response1.append(inputLine);
            sout.write(inputLine.getBytes());
        }
        in.close();

        sout.flush();

    }
```

---- other part of code --- didnt paste here

> From : ProxyServlet.java 
>   http:blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2014/05/proxy-servlet-to-forward-requests-to.html

I changed the url directly to the internal site

when I access the servlet, it looks like its getting the html from the remote site, but instead of rendering it, it just shows the html in plain text.

tried changing USER_AGENT value, didnt help..

Any pointers ?

Comment: you need to set response Content-Type to `text/html`. more precisely, the proxy needs to forward request/response headers between client/server. if you need a standalone proxy, consider using [my library](http://bayou.io/release/0.9/docs/http/Http_Intermediary.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {                 
        String url = "http://internalserver/path";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        //=============================
        response.setContentType(con.getContentType());
        int r=0;PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        while((r=con.getInputStream().read())!=-1){out.write(r);}
        //=============================
    }
```